# .Net MVC Razor submit form post action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, razor, http-post

I have an html form like:

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>Index</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="mercForm" action="http://someurl.com/" method="post">

            <input type="hidden" name="some_input" value="206">            

            <input type="submit" value="sub" />
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

When I post this form by clicking submit button, the new window opens with the posted values. But, I want to implement the same form into a MVC Razor page. I habe tried some code but I failed. New window does not open.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("http://some url.com/","SomeController", FormMethod.Post, null))
        {               
                <input type="hidden" name="some_input" value="206">                    
                <input type="submit" value="sub" />            
    }
```

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1):

As I know Html.BeginForm does not take 1st argument as some url, it should be some Action name.

If you want to post your form data to some third party web site then just collect the data inside an action directly and process the form post using HttpWebRequest.